# Access company files with Quickbooks multi user mode

Tags: windows-7, networking, multiple-users, quickbooks

We're using Quickbooks enterprise 7.0 contractor edition (I know, it's old...)

We have a computer set up in the office that has the company server/copy of QB install, it's running in multi user mode and the database manager has been told to scan for company files in the directory they're currently at which is a local folder of the machine acting as the server.

I've tried looking though everything but can't find out how to access these files from the other "client" copies of QB on other computers on the network. How do I set up the other computers to look for files at the location of that server? I have the ip of the server etc but can't find where to put that info. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

On the machine that has the QB Files, create a share for that folder.

Now, on the computer running the QB Server Manager, set it to scan for `\\fileservername\sharename`

Pretty simple, unless I'm missing your point.

If you want your clients to access those files, just create a shortcut to the above-mentioned share folder and place the shortcut on your client's desktop.  Or you could add that folder as a library in Windows Explorer.  To get it into QuickBook's Recently-Used list, just open it once.